# "Group" rows based on one column, then create new columns for the possible combinations of existing other columns' values

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe of the following form:

| date | I1 | I2 | F1 | F2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | A | v1 | v9 |
| 1 | 1 | B | v2 | v10 |
| 1 | 10 | A | v3 | v11 |
| 1 | 10 | B | v4 | v12 |
| 2 | 1 | A | v5 | v13 |
| 2 | 1 | B | v6 | v14 |
| 2 | 10 | A | v7 | v15 |
| 2 | 10 | B | v8 | v16 |

I want to create new columns based on the possible combinations of values from 'I1' and 'I2', and have the corresponding values all in one row (for the same date). The resulting dataframe should look like this (up to order of columns, which doesn't matter and I just chose one for visualization purposes):

| date | F1-1-A | F1-1-B | F1-10-A | F1-10-B | F2-1-A | F2-1-B | F2-10-A | F2-10-B |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | v1 | v2 | v3 | v4 | v9 | v10 | v11 | v12 |
| 2 | v5 | v6 | v7 | v8 | v13 | v14 | v15 | v16 |

What is the most concise  and **general** way to achieve this in pandas?

Comment: what did you try?

Comment: @sammywemmy I tried to use ```.groupby()``` on date, but failed to come up with a corresponding ```f``` for ```.agg(f)``` or ```.apply(f)``` which would achieve what I want. Specifically, I didn't know how to 'collapse' the original dataframe in such a way that I create multiple columns at once. I'm used to do ```df['new'] = df.groupby(...).agg(...)```.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're looking for a pivot.  Once you do this, you will need to join the multi-index column names to flatten it out.

```
df = df.pivot(index='date',columns=['I1','I2'], values=['F1','F2'])
df.columns = ['-'.join(map(str,x)) for x in df.columns]
df.reset_index(inplace=True)
```

Output

```
   date F1-1-A F1-1-B F1-10-A F1-10-B F2-1-A F2-1-B F2-10-A F2-10-B
0     1     v1     v2      v3      v4     v9    v10     v11     v12
1     2     v5     v6      v7      v8    v13    v14     v15     v16
```

Answer (score 3):

[@Chris' solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69548114/4518341) works great; a bit of an abstraction is possible with [`pivot_wider`](https://pyjanitor-devs.github.io/pyjanitor/reference/janitor.functions/janitor.pivot_wider.html) from `pyjanitor`, to flatten the columns (or do some other manipulation if needed):

```py
#pip install git+https://github.com/pyjanitor-devs/pyjanitor.git
import pandas as pd
import janitor
df.pivot_wider(index='date', names_from=['I1', 'I2'], names_sep='-')

   date F1-1-A F1-1-B F1-10-A F1-10-B F2-1-A F2-1-B F2-10-A F2-10-B
0     1     v1     v2      v3      v4     v9    v10     v11     v12
1     2     v5     v6      v7      v8    v13    v14     v15     v16
```

Note that pivot works only if the combination of index and columns is unique; if it isn't, a better option would be `pivot_table`.